# How to Copy Range And Paste in 1 Column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Anyone Have Some Idea to make something like this with VBA in Excel . Please...

```
Range (D2 : M4) 

1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

[image: Sample Data]

to be pasted just on 1 column B or Range (B3 : B33) like below:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

....etc

30
```

[image: Results]

Comment: `[B3:B33] = "=row(a1)"` :] (jk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to paste only values

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("D2:M4")
        Range("B3").Offset(i).Value = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

if you need to paste "all" cell

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("D2:M4")
        cell.Copy Destination:=Range("B3").Offset(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. It will work

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 4
        If i = 2 Then
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & i, "M" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & i, "M" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Coool. It works perfectly. Tank you @ KarthickGunasekaran

Comment: Kindly it as answer so that it will be helpful for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an accepted answer, but here is an alternative solution using formula **TRANSPOSE**:

```
Sub TransposeData()
Dim Data As Range, iRow&, RowData&, ColData&

Set Data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:M4")
RowData = Data.Rows.Count: ColData = Data.Columns.Count

For iRow = 1 To RowData
    Range("B" & 3 + (iRow - 1) * ColData).Resize(ColData, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Data.Rows(iRow))
Next

End Sub
```

Note that it only copy-paste the value, its format's excluded.